# Singleton vs. third-party libraries

Tags: cocoa, singleton, afnetworking, appdelegate

I'm familiar with the concept of [Singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Singleton.html) and this mechanism is pretty handy but..
What happens in case I want one, shared instance of some third-party class e.g. `AFHTTPRequestOperation` or maybe some Magical Record?
**What should I do when I'm using one object from external class in many controllers?** Or maybe it is a good practice to instantiate a new object in each controller?

Comment: You can always subclass the class you want to have a singleton object of and add it `+(that_class *)sharedInstance` or something...

Comment: Okey, but is this the way it should be done? I mean what is a good practice?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with that - it all depends of course on you application structure. In the previous (1.0) version of `AFNetworking` a singleton of `AFHTTPClient` was very common - a good example here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course

Comment: Though `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` would be probably a more likely candidate to make a singleton of than `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. Check "Subclassing Notes" here http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.2/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html

Comment: The singleton "factory" does not need to be a method of the class being served.  This is the standard "pattern", of course, but you can get the singleton effect using a "3rd party" "factory".

Comment: @HotLicks you're right but in this case class must provide factory methods for us.

Comment: Why must it?  The factory method has no dependency on the type of object it's serving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `Magical Record` but for `AFNewtorking` it definitely makes sense to make a singleton in many cases.

Though singleton of `AFHTTPRequestOperation` doesn't sound quite right. Much better candidate would be `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

Quote from [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager Class Reference](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.2/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html)

> Developers targeting iOS 7 or Mac OS X 10.9 or later that deal
>   extensively with a web service are encouraged to subclass
>   AFHTTPSessionManager, providing a class method that returns a shared
>   singleton object on which authentication and other configuration can
>   be shared across the application.
>
> For developers targeting iOS 6 or Mac OS X 10.8 or earlier,
>   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager may be used to similar effect.

It was similar with `AFHTTPCLient` in <2.0 versions.

One good reference would also be [this tutorial by Scott Sherwood](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course) on (as always) Ray Wenderlich blog.

Comment: It's good to hear that my personal feelings were good and they match the other people feelings!

Comment: Yep, intuition is underrated :) Hot Licks has a point there - no need to subclass when all you need is a ready made singleton object.